# socket connection in servlet class

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to establish a tcp connection through which I want to share data from one webform(jsp page) to another web page with same content.

below is servlet which gets called when clicking button on jsp page. As I checked the port which trying to connect is in listening state and from servlet it should get redirected to receiver form but it just keeps loading.

but program is getting stuck at **Socket insocket = socket.accept();** this line.
I searched in other resources as well but got answer as **"Socket.accept() hangs by design until a client connects to the port that is being waited on, in this case, port 8189. Your program is working fine"**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String first = request.getParameter("first_name");
        String last = request.getParameter("last_name");
        String name = first + " " + last;
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        byte buffer[] = new byte[10240];
        buffer = name.getBytes();
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(4333);
            Socket insocket = socket.accept();
            OutputStream outSocket = insocket.getOutputStream();
            outSocket.write(buffer);

            response.sendRedirect("receiver.jsp");
        } catch (java.net.ConnectException e) {
            System.out.println("server application not started.....");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not sure how to explain it much better than what you already have found. Once you get to the `socket.accept()` call it will hang there until something else connect to that server port.

Comment: This entire setup doesn't seem very stable though. If you get another post request to the same servlet while the first one is waiting, that request will fail as you will not be able to have two different threads listening to the same server socket. I suggest you revisit design for this solution.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian I actually want to implement Co-Browsing in a web form where what  ever data he puts in the field shoul reflect on admin web page.... can you suggest something

Comment: Apart from the answer from Stephen C below you could also save the state in your application (for example in a database or in memory depending on your needs) and poll the state on the other page directly from your page. There should be quite a few examples for that on the web.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to establish a socket-like connection between a web browser or client and a web server is to use WebSockets.  This causes the connection used for the HTTP request / response to be taken over for bidirectional socket communication.  It is a widely supported extension to the HTTP protocol.

If you want to connect two or more web browsers or web clients via the web server, you need to  establish WebSockets between each browser server, and then the server needs to route the information from between the server ends of the WebSockets.

The implementation details will depend on the technology stack used on the client and server sides.  You could start by reading the following:

- The Wikipedia [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) article.
- [A Guide to the Java API for WebSocket](https://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets)
- [RFC 6455 - The WebSocket Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)

---

They way you are trying to do it looks like it won't work.  Even if it does kind of work, there will be issues with managing the connections that you have established ... leading to resource leakage, problems with recycling ports, etcetera.  And then you need to deal with potential security issues; e.g. establishing that the client that connects to the `ServerSocket` port you are listening on is not some interloper.